# How to add to an instance variable in OOP but have it not returned as a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am a beginner to OOP in python as I have not yet learned about it in school. I understand the basics, like you can have`self.variables` and they are different for each time you use a class. But I do not know how to add to these variables as shown below:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, fname, sname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.sname = sname
        self.fullname = '{} {}'.format(fname, sname)
        self.email = '{}.{}@email.com'.format(fname, sname)


class Teacher(Person):

    def __init__(self, fname, sname, subject):
        super().__init__(fname, sname)
        self.subjects = subject

    def add_subject(self, sub):
        self.subjects.append(sub)

    def del_subject(self, sub):
        self.subjects.delete(sub)


class Student(Person):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(fname, sname)
        pass


t1 = Teacher('John', 'Becker', 'Maths')
print(t1.fullname)
t1.add_subject(input("Add Subject: "))
print('Subjects: ')
for i in t1.subjects:
    print("=====> "+i)
```

When I run the code:

```
John Becker
Add Subject: A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Desktop/Documents/YEAR 9/Computing/test.py", line 32, in <module>
    t1.add_subject(input("Add Subject: "))
  File "C:/Desktop/Documents/YEAR 9/Computing/test.py", line 17, in add_subject
    self.subjects.append(sub)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I also watched tutorials by Corey Schafer on Youtube, and I made sure to copy the style of his code **exactly** how he did it, but it still doesn't end up the same when I run it.
I have tried to make the `self.subjects = subject.split(" ")`, and this works, but if i were to print the subjects of t1, it would print a list. Is there a way to alter the code in the `class Teacher:` so that the subjects are returned as a  string rather than typing `print(subjects.join(" "))` Every time?

Edit: Ignore `class Student`, It is not finished, and also the `def del_subject`.

Comment: Look, `self.subjects` can either be a `list` or `str`, it makes sense for it to be a `list`. You could add a `def show_subjects(self)` method that simply does `print('' ".join(subjects))` for convenience.

Comment: Your `Student` constructor is incorrect. You need to make it `def __init__(self, fname, sname)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject variable is initiated in the __init__ with the 3rd variable. In your example this is set to 'Maths', a string. Perhaps that needs to be a list of subjects? In that case you need to pass a list to the constructor. Then subjects will be a list and append will work when you call add_subject.

```
t1 = Teacher('John', 'Becker', ['Maths'])
print(t1.fullname)
t1.add_subject(input("Add Subject: "))
```

Comment: Be careful when passing lists into constructors though. It's usually a better idea to copy the list, otherwise it's difficult to keep track of who has the ability to modify the list.

Comment: @EdwardMinnix not an issue if you are passing a list literal. But yes, care should be taken.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is in your constructor for `Teacher`. For example `t = Teacher('John', 'Doe', 'math')` means that `t.subjects` is `'math'`, not `['math']`.

To fix this you could either change it to:

```
 class Teacher(Person):
     def __init__(self, fname, sname, subject):
         ...
         self.subjects = [subject]
```

Or you could have

```
 class Teacher(Person):
     def __init__(self, fname, sname, *subjects):
         ...
         self.subjects = list(subjects)
```

Which will give the teacher the list of subjects passed in. So you'd have

```
 >>> t = Teacher('John', 'Doe', 'math')
 >>> t.subjects
 ['math']

 >>> t2 = Teacher('Jane', 'Smith', 'history', 'biology')
 >>> t2.subjects
 ['history', 'biology']
```

For the `del_subject` method, you'll need to use the `list.remove` method. The `list` class has no method `delete`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you, missed that at first. Just edited my answer to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way, as a beginner is:

```
class Teacher(Person):

    def __init__(self, fname, sname, *subject):
        super().__init__(fname, sname)
        self.subjects = list(subject)

    def get_subjects(self):
        return ' '.join(self.subjects)
```

You can get a comma separated string of subjects using

```
return ','.join(self.subjects)
```